# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetMonth(System.DateTime)' method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to select items in special month of `PersianCalendar` .

I use this linq.

```
 var calendar = new PersianCalendar();
 var month = calendar.GetMonth(DateTime.Now);
 var referreds= _db.Referreds.Where(m => calendar.GetMonth(m.CreatedDateTime) == month);
```

But i get error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetMonth(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

How do i select items with special month in linq??

Comment: A linq query must be able to be converted to a sql query (sql does not have a method `GetMonth()`)

Comment: You can easily get month from data using `Month` property as LINQ to Entities known how to translate it into SQL. But using persian (or any other) calendar? There is no way you're going to get a valid SQL out of it.

Comment: I use `PersianCalendar`. and want to get count of items that have CreatedDateTime with special month of Persian Calender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the PersianCalendar within LINQ to Entities directly (amongst other reasons, because the underlying databases do not have explicit support for it). What will work:

1. Calculate the first day of the month using *PersianCalendar.ToDateTime*
2. Calculate the first day of the next month
3. Use those values to query

   _db.Referreds.Where(m => m.CreatedDateTime >= firstDayOfMonth && m.CreatedDateTime < firstDayOfNextMonth);

I am assuming here that the Persian calendar has the same basic properties as the Gregorian calendar. If not, I'm sure Jon Skeet will step in to correct me.